# Check my logical error please

Tags: java

If the input is `x = y + 5`

the output must be:

```
Token 1 is x is identifier
Token 2 is =
Token 3 is y is identifier
Token 4 is +
Token 5 is 5
```

and this is the code i did i dont know whats wrong in my if condition !!

```
char[] ident = {'x','y','z','a','b','c','k'};

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please Enter Your String");
String x = sc.nextLine();


StringTokenizer t = new StringTokenizer(x);

for (int k = 0; k < ident.length; k++) {
    for (int j = 1; j < x.length()+1; j++) {
        char m = x.charAt(j);


        if (m==ident[k]) {

            System.out.println("Token " + j + " is " + t.nextToken()+" is identifier");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Token " + j + " is " + t.nextToken());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: run the code to know the issue :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two loops nether StringTokenizer. You could do it like:

```
final String str = new String(ident);
char m;
for (int j = 0; j < x.length(); j++) {
    m = x.charAt(j);
    if (str.indexOf(m) >= 0) {
       System.out.println("Token " + j + " is " + m+" is identifier");
    } else {
       System.out.println("Token " + j + " is " + m);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please close this question by accepting the answer if you think it helped so that others might use it as a reference in near future.